# how to download apk and save in mobile memory instead of SD Card using Phonegap with webIntent AND fileApi

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, webintents

can anyone please point to me towards right direction to do such task i want to download apk from URL and if new version available then it will download apk from that url and after downloading it must save file in mobile memory instead of SDCard i m using cordova 2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

this will definatly helps you
[phonegap file api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)
use file transfer api.

Answer (score 0):

Is there reference link you may get answer

[PhoneGap's File API](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/9/PhoneGaps-File-API)

[Mobile File Explorer with PhoneGap/Cordova and](http://www.digitalnoiz.com/mobile-development/mobile-file-explorer-with-phonegapcordova-and-jquery-mobile-part-1/)